# Issue losing session in Dotnetnuke

Tags: session, dotnetnuke

- I have a problem, that is lost session when logging in to the Administrator account.
- I login successful to the Administrator account, but when clicking on any page that the is lost session, other accounts will not be

Sorry my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically occurs when you are changing domains for your site. Are you in www in one case, them not after you get logged out? If so, check your portal aliases

Comment: I solved this problem, I assigned "PortalId" parameter in the URL. Thank you!